# Why combine all jars together?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, jar, build

I have create RESTful web service based on the JAX-RS and used Jersey embedded web server. My ant script compiles code successfully while it gives me error `ClassNotFoundException` when I run my `main class`. So after doing research I came up with solution & here it goes [java build ant file with external jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875244/java-build-ant-file-with-external-jar-files) . What I did was created a bundled jar file try to execute that & it works perfectly fine. I want to know the reason behind :

- why this solution works ?
- Why I should combine all jar file ?

Is it similar to war file which we create following J2EE architecture otherwise war will not be extracted by server ( say TOMCAT ) & in my case jar file for Jersey embedded HTTP server?

EDIT:
Here is my ant `build.xml` file

```
<property name="lib.dir" value="${user.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${user.dir}/build"/>
<property name="build.lib.dir" value="${build.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="build.classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="${user.dir}/src/main/java"/>
<property name="main.class" value="com.assignment.ConsoleServer"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="copy_jars" depends="init" >
    <copy todir="${build.lib.dir}" >
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="copy_jars">

    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${build.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${build.classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main.class}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${build.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Here is my folder structure

[image]

P.S. I am not java expert so pardon me if this question is stupid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create JAR file without including external dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264153/create-jar-file-without-including-external-dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why this solution works?

In your particular case, you probably didn't include all of the necessary dependencies in your deployment in your previous.  (It is not clear from your question how you were originally doing the deployment.)

Now you have put all of the application and dependent class files, etc into one JAR file, and presumably you are deploying / running that file.  It works because *now* it has everything that it needs to run ... which it didn't before.

> Why I should combine all jar file?

In your case I suspect that it was not strictly necessary.  There was probably a way to "deploy" all of the dependencies without combining them into a single JAR file.

However, there is one case where a "uber-jar" has advantages.  That is when the JAR is intended to be an "executable" JAR, and you want to be able to distribute / install it as a single file.  (And executable JAR 
file *can* refer to external JARs, etc, but the way that you have to do 
it is "fragile".)

> Is it similar to war file ... ?

Sort of, though a WAR file contains JAR files ... and typically other kinds of resources that the web-container understands.

Comment: Kindly please check my edited question .. I have added ant file & folder structure

Comment: actually the point is my ant successfully combile all my java code & when I try to run that main class file via ant it throws ClassNotFoundExcpetion .. although I include classpath at the runtime as well. Since it didn't work so I move to above mentioned solution and it worked. You are saying that `it has everything that it needs to run` but how come it has everything in jar and not in class file .. if it didn't have then how come it compile everything without error

Comment: It is obviously something to do with the *runtime* classpath, rather than the *compile time* classpath.  It may also be related to you having two different versions of the STAX on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The solution works because you packed all you service classes and depending libraries in one jar. That jar and everything inside will be in the class path and visible to your execution virtual machines class loader. 
If you leave your depending libraries out your Jersey Web server needs to have them on it's class path, then you wouldn't get `ClassNotFoundExcpetion`

You shouldn't pack web application in single jar. You should crate war file where you dependencies will be placed inside WEB-INF/lib. You would easily then deploy that war on any application server. Switching to Maven instead of Ant can help a lot.

EDIT: After you added more details to description and ant

If you don't want to use fat-jar you can either

- modify your ant`java` task to specify classpath that will reference
  all external libraries (basically telling ant how to build
  `-classpath` parameter    for `java -jar` command
- **even better**, modify your `javac` ant task by making complete Manifest    file that specifies `Class-Path` correctly, take a better
  look at the    solution (at the bottom) of the answer you linked   ([java build ant file with external jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875244/java-build-ant-file-with-external-jar-files))

For completness reference on Manifest [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Comment: So you mean to say that I create war file but am using jetty embedded server so no idea how I can deploy there. I know how to deploy war in tomcat but no idea about jetty server. Also I used maven as well and using intelliJ so it works fine in IDE .. but i created ant build file just to check the working under the hood

Comment: I never tried Jersey, but it seems that you are treating this application as a standalone application - therefore you had to pack everything into one Java Application Archive ( jar file). Alternatively if you wish not to pack all depending libraries into your jar you don't have to as long you JVM has them on it's class path.

Comment: ooking at you ant file you should be able to run your thin jar if you pass classpath correctly to ant run target! - have you double checked you are doing this correctly? Is your Manifest file present in the jar? What is the Class-Path value in the manifest file? - [I've amended my description]