# Java why is my jar file so big?

Tags: java

I have a pretty simple (And short) program that when compiled is somehow 26.9 MB?

I used a online java decompiler and all this came up:
[image: imgur link]

My program uses one java file which is `main.java`:

}

Why is my program so large?

Comment: Is this your jar (created by you) or some third party jar?

Comment: How do you build your jar?

Comment: Most probably this JAR contains some dependent libraries. Besides "your simple program"

Comment: this is my jar, it's only 70 lines

Comment: @RobertNavado I use intellij

Comment: Can you post your 70 lines code?

Comment: Selenium and PhantomJs are quite the dependencies if you package them in your jar. They easily give you your 26.9 MB

Comment: Yes, I posted it. probably really ugly, but it's my first program

Comment: That `org.openqa.selenium` answers everything. Selenium library has lots of dependencies. IntelliJ is just adding it automatically for you.

Comment: Okay, so it's because of org.openqa.selenium.. is there anyway to get it down just a little bit?

Comment: You have only the option to provide Selenium and PhantomJs as separate libraries. But the overall size won't change much. (it may even get bigger with more jar files)

Comment: you can create the jar without the dependencies, but those files are still going to be needed to run it, so its really only saving space for people who already have the libraries installed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264153/create-jar-file-without-including-external-dependencies .. You could also try throwing proguard into the mix.

Comment: For that you would have to analyze your code and try to find out only specifics usages of selenium in your code, then just add specific dependencies by hand. But that will be a really long and hard work. OR even worst, download the selenium code and cut out what it isn't be used.

Comment: If you really want to bring the size down one way would be to get rid of Selenium and use plain web requests - however give the nature of the page you're automating that might be easier said than done (I doubt they're making it very automation friendly, the opposite probably)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said above, IntelliJ will package the dependencies into the created JAR file. You can see this by extracting the JAR `jar xf file.jar` file and taking a look in the contents.

What you can do is (as suggested) use Maven (https://maven.apache.org/install.html) this will allow you to create Dependencies that you can then supply to your code on the classpath.

With IntelliJ click File > New > Project,

Pick Maven from the list and choose a Project SDK.

Next give your project a Group ID (com.company) and Artifact ID (myproject); leave Version as is for now.

Now, give you project a local name (this will be the folder that gets created on your IdeaProjects directory.

IntelliJ will popup a message to you saying that "Maven projects need to be imported", I always Enable Auto-Import and then just maintain the `pom.xml` file.

This will create you a project, find you pom.xml file: it will look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version><!-- Pick a different version if needed -->
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now you can package your project by running `mvn package` from the terminal, and your jar file will be saved into a `target` directory. It will be very small as it will contain only your code.

To run the program, you can then do the following:

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.Test" -Dexec.args="space separated arguments"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using a lot of external libraries (now when you provided the code seems that they pulled by Selenium)  in your code and intellij  kindly packs them together into one jar, so you can run your program without need to care about class path in runtime.

To reduce the size of your jar I can suggest the following approaches:

1. Reduce amount of external libraries (imported classes). For example don't include **java.io.*** but only the class you're actually using.
2. Build proper compilation script using ant or maven. Then your jar will include only your classes and will be very small relatively to what you have now. However to run your code you'll need to care about having all required libs in runtime.

Comment: There are no such `org.apache.commons.*` on his code.

Comment: I didn't know what exactly do you have in this code, because you didn't provide it from the beginning. But read carefully, that's example! Just don't include full namespace when you need only one class.

Comment: The code was provided in the question. Read it carefully. And it is not mine.

Comment: Not from the beginning.

Comment: Jorge, sorry for being personal. As the question changes so the answer does.

Comment: Whoever wants to post answers here should be prepared to receive critics  about the provided answer. If you can't handle it you shouldn't be answering. That's why we downvote with an explanation so one would known what is wrong and fix it, then the downvote will be probably retracted as I did. Apologies accepted. Just don't take it personal next time. :)

Comment: Useless import statements only increase the size of the source code, not of the compiled byte code.

Comment: It's really depends on packaging mechanism. Part may include different classes from different librarry versions depending on deeper dependencies.